# Ansible filter using ad-hoc command

Tags: ansible

How can I filter the `nocache` block or `free` block using ad-hoc command? I tried `ansible centos1 -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_memory_mb.nocache'` but doesn't filter it out.

```
ansible centos1 -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_memory_mb'
centos1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_memory_mb": {
            "nocache": {
                "free": 11808,
                "used": 926
            },
            "real": {
                "free": 10686,
                "total": 12734,
                "used": 2048
            },
            "swap": {
                "cached": 0,
                "free": 4096,
                "total": 4096,
                "used": 0
            }
        },
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try with the ansible command, you have to mix with grep and head:

```
ansible centos -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_memory_mb' | grep -Eo [0-9]+ | head -1
```

but you should use playbook: the var result will contain the value desired.

```
- name: test
  hosts: centos1
  
  tasks:
    - name: set vars
      set_fact: result="{{ ansible_memory_mb.nocache.free}}" 
    - name: show
      debug:
        var: result
```

---

result:

```
TASK [show] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": "712"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same question a had some months ago, but the answer is if you need access to specific internal block, you need to use a Ansible Playbook, unfortunately you can not do it with ad-hoc commands. For example in date time of your localhost:

`ansible -m setup localhost -a 'filter=ansible_date_time'`

Will return a lot of specific information, like seconds, year, minute, and others. And if you want only return the format date like '2021-10-16' you need to use a playbook. Here some specific playbook to create a folder with date specific format:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Collect Year, Month and Day.
      setup:
        filter: "ansible_date_time"
        gather_subset: "!all"
    
    - name: Put today's date in a variable.
      set_fact:
        DTG: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}"

    - name: Create directory with the following path C:\bkp_"year-month-day"\Switches\
      file:
        path: /mnt/c/bkp_{{ hostvars.localhost.DTG }}/Switches/
        state: directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is available without a manipulated script. for a quick solution, you can run below adhoc commands

```
ansible centos -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_memtotal_mb'
ansible centos -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_memfree_mb'
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to filter it out. Not trying to get the value. Any idea how to filter it using the ad-hoc command? its a dictionary  so I'm trying to find out how to filter it when using ad-hoc command

Comment: did you try with shell module by ad hoc command:-
#ansible centos -m shell -a "free -wh"

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html):

> This module is automatically called by playbooks to gather useful variables about remote hosts that can be used in playbooks. It can also be executed directly by `/usr/bin/ansible` to check what variables are available to a host.

Different parameters like `subset`, `filter`, limit the information that is gathered from hosts. Such data is stored in `ansible_facts` dict.

And, most importantly:

> The filter option filters only the first level subkey below ansible_facts

Although, when `setup` module is run from playbook (or as `gather_facts: true`), we can access the facts and its subkeys/elements because its *available as a variable*.

A very simple playbook can achieve what you want. Example:

```yaml
# play.yml

- hosts: "{{ my_hosts }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: filter memory facts
      setup:
        filter: ansible_memory_mb

    # note that an intermediate set_fact task is not required as such
    - name: show memory nocache values
      debug:
        var: ansible_memory_mb.nocache
```

Then run it instead of ad-hoc command (on `centos1`):

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -e "my_hosts=centos1" -i <inventory-path>
```